# Show that $E=\mathbb{R}u\oplus\mathbb{R}v$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\dim E\ge 2$, $\varphi$ is an **alternating bilinear** form and  **nondegenerate**, we suppose there exists $u,v\in E$ such that $\varphi(u,v)=1$
>
> **Show that $E=\mathbb{R}u\oplus\mathbb{R}v$**

At first I fund that $\mathbb{R}u\cap\mathbb{R}v=\{0_E\}$

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}u\cap\mathbb{R}v$ then $x=\lambda u =\gamma v$ and $\varphi(x,x)=0=\lambda\gamma\varphi(u,v)=\lambda\gamma$ we deduce $\lambda=\gamma =0$

**For the rest**, I sruggle a little. I have proven that $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent because $\varphi(u,v)\ne 0$ which means $\dim E\ge 2$, if I show $\dim E\le 2$, it's done (but I don't know how to proceed), I must use the property that $\varphi$ is nondegenerate but I don't know how????

Comment: Did you mean $\dim E = 2$?

Comment: That is what I want to show

Comment: You state in bold that you want to show $E = \mathbb{R}u \oplus \mathbb{R}v$. Perhaps you could clarify what you are assuming and what you are hoping to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. On $E=\mathbb R^4$ let
$$
\varphi(u,v) = u^t
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
v.
$$
Now $\varphi(e_1, e_2) = 1$ but $e_1$ and $e_2$ do not span $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Ok, I understood, that is the reason I can't find the solution, I tried to find a counter example with $\mathbb{R}^3$ and nothing...  thank you very mush